# intrusive pointers from this

Tags: boost, smart-pointers

How can a this pointer be passed to a method that expects intrusive_ptr (such as the one from boost)? For shared_ptrs there is `enable_shared_from_this`.

Answer (score 2):

When using `intrusive_ptr` the class itself is responsible for handling its reference counts. So passing a pointer to itself is easy!

All it has to do is increment its own reference counter and pass `this`. Done.